# Generalizing WCF client

Tags: wcf, reflection

I am new to WCF and face a pretty challenging task.

I have 10+ wsdl files that look almost the same. These in turn can be generated to class with their names, CO1, CO2, CO3... And they each have many methods, CO1Query, CO1Add, CO1Update, etc.

Instead of having all these files, or combining them to a single class, and references to do CO1Channel.CO1Query(CO1Input), ... etc

I would like to have a single general class name CO and all members/methods with CO.

Given the index 1-10, how can I use this single class to call all these methods? So, C01, CO2 are the real objects with the namespaces but CO is the one that we generalize and defined in the code.

I found this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility.aspx and maybe one of these 3 helps.

1. DataContractResolver,
2. EndPointBehavior/OperationBehavior
3. IObjectReference

No. 1 requires generating different class dynamically which I try to avoid.
No. 2 select different operation, so in stead of COQuery do CO1Query but I think this is not defined
No. 3 Looks promising and has a GetRealObject method